# Is water pipe grounding achieved thru pipe or thru water?

Tags: grounding

I've got a 1901 house, with copper (new) piping.  Some of the electrical (old knob and tube circuits) are grounded to the water pipes.  The copper pipe goes out to my shutoff valve located outside. so far so good.  However, the waterpipe from the shutoff valve to the ground has been replaced with PVC.  So, the contact with the ground is actually a PVC waterpipe for at least 1' above ground. My question - Is this considered to be safely grounded?    (or do I need to install a ground rod from the cu pipe?).

Comment: The grounding is accomplished through the metal pipe. *Pure* water is an effective electrical insulator. It's only conductive when there are dissolved salts in it (not just NaCl, but any metal salts).

Comment: Thank you @Craig !  (I guess I naturally think of water as a conductor) ~ I'd better fix that right away. Thanks again!

Comment: @JTinOakland, generally speaking, water _is_ a conductor. You don't really come across pure water in the real world, or at least not in quantities where you'd be worried about its conducting or insulating abilities. However I am by no means saying water is an appropriate path to ground.

Comment: While generally speaking, water may be a conductor, in the context of home wiring, it is not. Using [this](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/resistance-resisitivity-d_1382.html) formula, a 1 m piece of 18 gauge wire would have a resistance of 0.02 ohms, but a 3/4" diameter pipe full of sea water would have a resistance of [41](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=(2.00*10%5E%E2%88%921+ohm+*+m)+(1+m)+%2F+((483+mm%5E2)(10*10%5E-6+m%5E2%2Fmm%5E2))) ohms, 2000 times worse. A short to that 41 ohm ground would only carry 3 amps - not enough to trip a breaker.

Comment: I found a source for [resistivity of tap water](http://chemistry.about.com/od/moleculescompounds/a/Table-Of-Electrical-Resistivity-And-Conductivity.htm), it ranges from 2×10^1 to 2×10^3 Ohm-m, so taking a value in the middle yields [41,000](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=(2.00*10%5E2+ohm+*+m)+(1+m)+%2F+((483mm%5E2)(10*10%5E-6+m%5E2%2Fmm%5E2))) ohms for that water pipe, higher than most people's skin resistance.

Comment: @Johnny ...so you're saying that if you were relying on 3/4" diameter column of seawater to divert the current of a 15A circuit away in the case of a fault, it would only divert enough to reduce the potential current flowing through *you* to 12A?  ;-)

Comment: @Craig: Well, it's worse than that - if a 120V hot wire was shorted to the ground wire, it would form a [resistive voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider#Resistive_divider). So say there's  1 Ohm of resistance in the copper ground wire that leads back to the pipe, and 41 Ohms of resistance from that pipe to ground. that means that there is now a potential of (41/(1+41))*120=[117V](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=(41%2F(1%2B41))*120) on the entire ground system, so touching any grounded appliance could give you a lethal shock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grounding is accomplished through the metal pipe, not through the water.

Pure water is an effective electrical insulator. It's only conductive when there are dissolved salts in it (not just NaCl, but any metal salts creating free ions floating around in the water). In that case, water can become a very good conductor. But it isn't really the water doing the conducting.

That PVC pipe is **not** creating a suitable path to ground.

You need to drive at least one grounding rod (probably an 8' copper or galvanized steel solid rod, which you can buy at your local home improvement warehouse), and run a #6 copper wire from that rod to your main service panel, where you'll bond it to the grounding bus. You **also** need to leave all of your copper and/or iron pipes bonded to the grounding bus in your main panel.

Comment: Check your local code requirements, of course, to see how many grounding rods you're actually required to drive, what size wire you're required to use and how you're required to bond the wire to the rods and back to your panel.

Answer (score 2):

Way back when it was allowed to run grounding conductors to any cold water pipe for equipment grounds for circuits. This allowance was removed from the code a LONG time ago due to the practice being potentially very unsafe.

When your water pipe was metallic going out into the yard it was being used as a grounding electrode and should have been bonded to the electrical panel. The grounding electrode and being in contact with the earth had NOTHING to do with the pipe being able to be used as a grounding source for circuits. The function of allowing it to be used to ground circuits came from the fact that the pipe was bonded to the main panel. 
Problem is, using the pipe as an equipment grounding conductor means that and problems or faults would have to go through every fitting and joint in the path back to the panel.

Comment: Would you elaborate a little on the pipe (in the old days) only being useful as a grounding electrode because of the bonding to the neutral in the panel? If the neutral to ground path at the transformer was compromised (happens from time to time) you would have no path to local earth ground at all and you could build up substantial voltage potential between the power company neutral and the local earth potential, right?

Comment: You're totally right about all the fittings and joints in the pipe causing problems, especially over time as old pipe corrodes, and especially since so much of the old pipe was iron or lead, which are much poorer conductors than copper (and steel is worse than raw iron), and iron and common steel are so susceptible to corruption. Lead is a relatively poor conductor, so soldered joints in copper pipe add resistance. Pipe dope or plumber's tape add huge resistance in iron pipe, and of course rust doesn't conduct as well as clean iron, etc.

Comment: The reason to connect to earth is not for fault clearing or for any kind of equipment ground purposes. The earth is used to stabilize voltage in cases of high voltage spikes or faults, mostly lightning. A metallic water pipe still must be used as an electrode if it exists and is in contact with the earth for 10' or more. My "old days" comment was about using the water piping in a house to connect an equipment ground.